# Question regarding capital letter in scientific report

Tags: capitalization

I'm writing a scientific report (due this evening), and I'm having some problems regarding capital letters. As usual, figures, tables, sections, etc., are given capital letters. 
Example:
Results given in Fig. 2. 
See Tabs. 4-5.

In one of the tables I have defined 14 integrals, where each integral is paired up with a number. These integrals are referred to by:
Integrals 3-4 in Tab. 2.

My question is this. Should I capitalize the I in integral, when referring to them in the middle of a sentence?

Should I say: When testing with integral 4. 
Or: When testing with Integral 4.

If the latter case, should I use an abbreviation for Integral, like I do for Figure (Fig.), Table (Tab.) and Section (Sec.)?

Answer (score 1):

I am by no means an expert in scientific paper writing, but it seems to me that it's more consistent to capitalize the term Integral, just like you do with the other numbered things.

Comment: I agree. It helps to think of this as the caption or title of a figure.

Comment: @Ingmar every German-speaker would agree.